# CefSharp isTrusted click event?

Tags: javascript, events, click, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm having trouble getting the CefSharp browser to invoke trusted clicks in the browser. Initiating a click event as follows in the JS (from CefSharp) is only halfway there:

```
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
element[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

The above method still theoretically fails the .isTrusted event property (even though the version of Chromium that CefSharp uses doesn't implement .isTrusted)

Knowing that soon Chromium will implement isTrusted, how can I get CefSharp to perform a trusted click on elements in the browser?

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this question